# AFNetworking 2.0 make a POST request

Tags: ios, rest, afnetworking, asihttprequest

I have a question about AFNetworking 2.0

I would to integrate AFNetworking 2.0 in my iOS app. Before the integration I use code like this to make a POST request:

```
NSString *string = [self.serverName stringByAppendingString:resource];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
__block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setUsername:username];
[request setPassword:password];

if(data != nil)
{
    [request setPostBody:data];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
}

[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    ....
}];


[request setFailedBlock:^{
    .....
}];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

In AFNetworking Integration I make a POST request in this way:

I use a singleton class :AFHTTPSessionManager.
I set:

```
self.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        self.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

POST request:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *requestParameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [requestParameters setObject:@"....." forKey:@"....."];

[self POST:@"/resource" parameters:requestParameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Ok");
    }
    failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Failed");
    }];
```

I have the same parameters and URL.

But in the second way the request fails. I have an error: Request failed: unacceptable (406)

This two ways are equivalent? In first way I set the parameters (transformed in NSData) into the body of request. Is correct this my second way?

Comment: Are you sure `resource` is identical to "`/resource`"? (First example and the second example)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure for resource as also parameters names and values.